# Negative origin of frame of UIView after subsequent layout

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, ios-autolayout

I get a frame = (-335 -560; 375 608) on 2nd and subsequent layouts, where the origin becomes negative (-335,-560).  This causes the view to be drawn off screen.  This view is the root view of a UIViewController.  The view is a composition of 10 subviews constrained vertically, like in a vertical-axis stack view.  I constrain the top anchor of the highest subview to this view's top anchor.

I don't know how to constrain this view's top anchor to be at (0,0) origin.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you're doing something really weird with a custom container view controller, your view controller's frame should be controlled by its parent view controller (and if your view controller is the window's root view controller, it should have the same frame as the window). If your view controller's origin is going negative, look to the parent. What is your parent view controller?

Comment: The root view controller is a UINavigationController, which is the parent of this view controller.  When I push a view controller, and then pop it, my view gets this weird frame.

Comment: Here's another weird thing: before the new view controller finishes appearing I can see that my old view changes its frame.

Comment: Are you laying out your views in Storyboard / IB? Or are you adding your *"10 subviews constrained vertically"* via code?

Comment: Programmatically - I have to because number of views is dynamic.  However, the subvienes are laid out correctly the first time.

Comment: OK - you'll need to show some of your code that is creating / laying out the views (obviously, what you are experiencing is not correct or common behavior).

Comment: Problem solved - turns out that "position is ambiguous" because I did not tie the view's top and left anchors to something.  And you can't, because that's the root view.  So I simply made my view be subview of the standard view controller top view, and tied its top/left anchors to its superview.  Now the frame of my view remains the same.  IMO this is silly that we need to keep around the default view, but it works, so whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach is to add own custom view as a subview to the default view controller view, and tie your custom view's position anchors to that view.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Super view is constraint Whether its frame have negative origins and set zero Spacing to corresponding view to superview . refer the image Attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw3P4.png)